# Package visible in Scala REPL but not in Eclipse in SBT project?

Tags: eclipse, scala, sbt, typesafe-activator

I have the following line in my `build.sbt`:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.bouncycastle" % "bcprov-jdk16" % "1.46"
```

When I go to REPL and launch my project there, the following works:

```
scala> import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider
import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider

scala> val a = new BouncyCastleProvider
a: org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider = BC version 1.46
```

But when I try to import the same package in Eclipse I get an error:

```
import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider
// object bouncycastle is not a member of package org
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Have you tried running "sbt eclipse"? That should create Eclipse project files, .classpath among them as well, which contains paths to dependencies.

Comment: @HarisOsmanagić thanks for the idea! I use Typesafe Activator and re-generating project files for Eclipse did help (I've decided to try this before `sbt eclipse`).

Comment: that's great to hear! Happy scaling.:)

Comment: @HarisOsmanagić could you use your comment as an answer so the question's answered? Thanks.

Comment: @JacekLaskowski Of course!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried running `sbt eclipse`? That should create Eclipse project files, `.classpath` among them as well, which contains paths to dependencies.

Unless you use a version of Eclipse with support for dependencies under sbt, you'll have to execute `sbt eclipse` every time you've changed them.